# Remove a control in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

Is there a way to remove a control in OpenLayers 3? I am creating a custom control that includes a textbox and a button for executing a function. I want the user to be able to click an "x" to dismiss the control and/or hit the esc key to "close" it.

Comment: Are you aware of `ol.Map#removeControl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is the

```
ol.Map.removeControl(yourControl);
```

[here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Map.html#removeControl) is it in the API Docs